# What can be the reason Grub cant install on Efi partition with windows?

Tags: grub-efi

I want to dual boot windows and ubuntu. I have UEFI mode and GPT partition. For the past week I have been trying to install grub on EFI partition but no matter what I try it just doesnt work. I have created a new efi partition of bigger size and deleted the old one, I use boot repair but it fails to install grub, I tried to manually install grub through live usb and terminal method but I get "unknown error -1". I install grub through windows cmd and it works but the ubuntu installation was not proper as there was a fatal error "cant install grub" during setup and it makes Ubuntu act weird and unstable. I created a partition with Bios_grub flags in gparted and it wont work. At this point its safe to say that I have tried 90% solutions online coz I have been obsessed with this for the past week and no matter what I do Grub just wont install. Every problem I solve leads to "unknown error -1" which I cant solve. I thought its Ubuntu 19.04 problem so I installed 18.04 but same error. I tried Linux mint and still same error. Grub just cant get installed on the Efi partition with windows so I created another Efi partition but same error. Can anyone tell why this may be? Is windows somehow blocking grub from installing? Coz I can install grub through windows cmd

Comment: Yes in default boot menu I have only USB UEFI boot option.

Comment: You can only have one ESP per drive, and default install by Ubiquity installer is to first drive, usually into the existing Windows ESP. A few systems have UEFI setting to "lock" ESP. A few have some minor corruption and need chkdsk (Windows) or dosfsck (Linux) on ESP. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: You do not need to create an EFI partition. It already exists as an ESP partition if you're adding Ubuntu to a Windows system. Try to make another one and it will cause conflict.